# Is it possible to get the status or partial results from a concurrent.futures.Future?

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

Is it possible to get the status of a job (`Future`) or even some partial results when using `concurrent.futures` package from Python?

As far as I saw you only are able to add callbacks for when the job is done with:

```
add_done_callback(fn)
```

method but not to get the status of it.

Comment: You can query whether the call is being executed with the method concurrent.futures.Future.running()

Comment: @Nitul
https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html : "running() 
    Return True if the call is currently being executed and cannot be cancelled." so no progress reported by that call.